# Making the first column in a table fixed when scrolling horizontally

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, html-table

Is it possible to make the first column fixed when you scroll horizontally?

The other columns would be scrolled, but the 1st column should remain visible.

JSFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/FSv9Y/

HTML (dummy data for testing this)

```
<div class="vScroll">
 <table style="width: 90%">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>A1 Component</th>
     <th>A2 Component</th>
     <th>A3 Component</th>
     <th>A4 Component</th>
     <th>A5 Component</th>
     <th>A6 Component</th>
     <th>A7 Component</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>Line Item 1</td>
     <td>Line Item 2</td>
     <td>Line Item 3</td>
     <td>Line Item 4</td>
     <td>Line Item 5</td>
     <td>Line Item 6</td>
     <td>Line Item 7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Line Item 1</td>
     <td>Line Item 2</td>
     <td>Line Item 3</td>
     <td>Line Item 4</td>
     <td>Line Item 5</td>
     <td>Line Item 6</td>
     <td>Line Item 7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Line Item 1</td>
     <td>Line Item 2</td>
     <td>Line Item 3</td>
     <td>Line Item 4</td>
     <td>Line Item 5</td>
     <td>Line Item 6</td>
     <td>Line Item 7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Line Item 1</td>
     <td>Line Item 2</td>
     <td>Line Item 3</td>
     <td>Line Item 4</td>
     <td>Line Item 5</td>
     <td>Line Item 6</td>
     <td>Line Item 7</td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

CSS (used for just the basic styling and scrolling on this demo)

```
/* Standardize Table Styling Across Browsers for Both Standard and Scrollable Tables */
table {border:none;border-collapse:collapse;line-height:18px;margin-right:1px;table-layout:fixed;}
th, td {margin:0px;padding:0px;}

/* Little Bit of Custom Styling for Flare */
th {background-color:#E9E9E9;border:solid 1px silver;}
td {border:solid 1px silver;}

/* Enable Scroll Styling Effect */
.vScroll {display:run-in;overflow-x:none;overflow-y:scroll;}

/* Fix Positioning Issue in IE 8 (and Earlier) and Mozilla */
.vScroll {border-left:solid 1px silver;}
.vScroll td:first-child {border-left:none;}
.vScroll thead, .vScroll tfoot {margin-left:-1px;}

/* Standardize Scrollbar in Safari to Be Same Width as Chrome, IE and Mozilla. */
::-webkit-scrollbar {width:16px;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {border-radius:10px;-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {background-color:silver;border-radius:10px;-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 3px rgba{0,0,0,0.5);}
```

JS

```
function ReSizeScrollTables () {
$(".vScroll").each(function (i,c) {
var ScrollBarWidth = 16; //IE, Chrome, Mozilla & Opera use Size 16 by default
var $Scroll = $(c);
var $Table = $Scroll.find("table");
var $Head = $Scroll.find("thead");
var $Foot = $Scroll.find("tfoot");
var $Body = $Scroll.find("tbody");

//Remove Cell Width Formatting
$Body.first("tr").find("th, td").each(function (i, c) { $(c).css("width", "auto"); });
$Head.find("th, td").each(function (i, c) { $(c).css("width", "auto"); });
$Foot.find("th, td").each(function (i, c) { $(c).css("width", "auto"); });

//Set Width of Table, Header, Footer and Body Elements
$Table.css("width", $Scroll.width() - ScrollBarWidth + 2);

//Disable positioning so browser can do all the hard work.
//This allows us to support min-width, max-width, nowrap, etc.
$header.css("position", "relative");
$footer.css("position", "relative");

//Navigate thru each cell hard coding the width so when the association
//is broken all of the columns will continue to align based on normal
//table rules. Only traverse the first row cells in the body for efficiency.
$body.first("tr").find("th, td").each(function (i, c) { $(c).css("width", GetWidth(c)); });
$header.find("th, td").each(function (i, c) { $(c).css("width", GetWidth(c)); });
$footer.find("th, td").each(function (i, c) { $(c).css("width", GetWidth(c)); });

//Enable positioning for fixed header positioning.
$header.css("position", "absolute");
$footer.css("position", "absolute");

$Table.css("width", $Scroll.width() - ScrollBarWidth - 3);

//Position Heading Based on Height of Heading
$Scroll.css("margin-top", ($Head.height() + 1) + "px");
$Head.css("margin-top", (($Head.height() - 1) * -1) + "px");

//Position Footer Based on Height of Scroll Host
$Scroll.css("margin-bottom", $Foot.css("height"));
$Foot.css("margin-top", $Scroll.height() - 1 + "px");
});
};

function GetWidth(c) {
var dWidth = $(c).attr(style);
return ((dWidth != null) && (dWidth.length > 0)) ? dWidth : $(c).css(style);
};

$(document).ready(function() { ReSizeScrollTables(); });
$(window).resize(function() { ReSizeScrollTables(); });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some time ago I search answer for this question and found optimal solution for me: fixed div with table with first column and absolute table under it with js calculated offset and size.

CSS:

```
.vScroll td:first-child {
    border-left:none; 
    position: fixed; 
    background-color: white; 
} 

.vScroll th:first-child {
    border-left:none; 
    position: fixed;
}
```

JS:

```
var maxw = 0;
var maxh = 0;

$(".vScroll th").each( function(){
    maxw = Math.max(maxw, parseInt( $(this).css("width"), 10 ));
    maxh = Math.max(maxh, parseInt( $(this).css("height"), 10 ));
});

$(".vScroll th").css({
    width: maxw
    , height: maxh
});

maxh = 0;

$(".vScroll td").each( function(){
    maxw = Math.max(maxw, parseInt( $(this).css("width"), 10 ));
    maxh = Math.max(maxh, parseInt( $(this).css("height"), 10 ));
});

$(".vScroll td:first-child").css({
    width: maxw
    , height: maxh
});
```

Comment: Yep would be a good solution however i need to be able to have this as 1 table rather than 2 because we have hidden forms inside hidden <tr> with colspans for width so need to work on a js solution maybe for it, im not sure.

Comment: .vScroll td:first-child {border-left:none; position: fixed; background-color: white; }

    .vScroll th:first-child {border-left:none; position: fixed; }

Comment: Ahhh seems to work lovely, not sure about IE7/8 yet but will have to fix that when i test it out. Is there anyway to make them inline with the other cells and full white background maybe? http://jsfiddle.net/FSv9Y/1/ - is updated with your css changes, would it be more cross browser you think if we done somehow in JS?

Comment: Use js to set height and width first column same as second or any other.

Comment: Sorry still learning :) how would i do is in JS so that it would grab the existing height with a custom width from the other TDs so they all match up as they can can change in size so would need to be flexible i guess rather than a fixed height. Thanks for your time with this  btw, really appreciate it but once that is cracked think it is then done.

Comment: Thanks a lot, ive integrated everything into the live environment on the table we have and some issues but will test it once ive sorted those.

Comment: Hi mate, im getting issues in my live site, 2 things the left fixed position on the column scrolls when you moving the main scroll bar down on the window and moves it out of the table, my TH titles are missing now but on fiddle they are not but the position and horizontal slides are not there any ideas? http://jsfiddle.net/FSv9Y/3/ your see the 1st 2 columns are under the fixed one as well and no scroll bar :( Thanks again

Comment: Resize 1-st column only once at start or exclude the first column from calculating max width and height.

Comment: Sorry VoidVolker, really new to JS and struggling and got to demo this in a few hours :( could you be so kind to maybe help me fix the jsfiddle so its working correctly with scrolling etc..?

Comment: Seems that width stuff we added breaks, as if i remove in version 3 its ok but all cells squashed up and not neat plus still sits under, im trying to play with it but if you can spare a moment to help me would be so grateful dude